# Увеличивается счётчик отклонённых правок, если предлагаемая правка отклонена Духом, как "конфликтующая с последующей правкой"

Tags: дефект, предлагаемые-правки, отклонённые-правки

[Правка, о которой идет речь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/435006). Как-то неприятно получать +1 в отклоненные просто так, хотя правка хорошая.

Comment: А что предлагаете делать в таких случаях?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Самое первое, что приходит в голову - вообще не отмечать ни как отмененную, ни как принятую.

Comment: @0xdb где связь? Правка в целом хорошая, независимо от того, что произойдёт с вопросом.

Comment: @0xdb правка повысила читабельность. Для меня это признак того, что правка хорошая.

Comment: @0xdb да я не требую, чтобы мою правку проверили и приняли, хотя вопрос будет закрыт. Я хочу, чтобы как минимум репу не отнимали, и счетчик отклоненных правок не увеличивался - я же не виноват, что закончил правку после того, как вопрос закрыли.

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar Согласен, комменты выше не по теме, будут удалены. Теперь по теме: репутация за откланение правки не снижается. Может вы счётчик правок имеете в виду?

Comment: @0xdb я ошибся - думал, что снижается. Да, сейчас я имею ввиду счетчик отклоненных правок.

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar А, то есть вот это: "Miron says reinstate Red Star предложил 42 одобренные и 14 отклонённых правок". А как вы этот счётчик запоминаете? Там действительно было "13 отклонённых" до правки указанной в вопросе?

Comment: @0xdb и это тоже не знаю. Но раз написано - отклонено, значит отклонено. Если не изменился, значит нужно надпись менять на более понятную

Comment: *вообще не отмечать ни как отмененную, ни как принятую* — тогда вы не поймёте что произошло. Вы думаете, что кому-то есть дело до вашей статистики правок?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я пойму это только если я буду следить за статистикой правок. Это дефект. Курочка по зёрнышку, знаете ли...

Comment: @0xdb вообще, насколько я помню, если много правок будет отклонено, то запретят правки делать (:

Comment: Да, счётчик считает: _Анонимный пользователь утвердил 1 и отклонил 1 предлагаемую правку_ . @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Сколько порог?

Comment: @0xdb не могу сказать точно. Но там явно большинство правок должно быть отклонено. ТС это явно не грозит)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ну тогда остаётся ТС посоветовать не править очень свежие сообщения, где вероятность параллельной правки наиболее высока, ну или подождать 2к репы (ему уже не долго). Что этот дефект будет исправлен - у меня почему то вызывает большое сомнение.